# How to make password file hashed with SHA1

Tags: passwords, sh

The `<passwordFile>` element is used to specify a file which has a set of username and password pairs. The format of username and password in this file is ${username}=${password which has been hashed with SHA1}, with one line per user.

**Examples**

Suppose the password file is `admins.properties`, which is located in `/home/locker`. You want to create two users as Administrators:

- one username is `nlohchab`, the password hashed with SHA1 is `ThmbShxAtJepX80c2JY1FzOEmUk=`
- the other one is `james`, the password hashed with SHA1 is `TfkgShslgJepX80c2JY1trwEskT=`

Answer (score 2):

1. SHA is a hashing algorithm, you can't encrypt anything with it.
2. your question is not programming-related and [ServerFault.com](http://ServerFault.com) is a better place for it.